# Cronjob is not running Python script on Raspberry

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, cron-task

On my Raspberry I try to run a Python script as a cronjob. The script does run and execute perfect via the console when I ask him to. However I cannot manage to run the task in cron. Why is this cronjob not working?

What I’ve did so far

1. Logged in as root user
2. Granted all rights at the .py file in the Finder to anybody and chmodded the file to 777
3. Edited both sudo crontab -e and crontab -e files and I did edit the /etc/crontab file (they are three different files(?!)).
4. Tested crons with each of the below cron codes (I did reboot after every edit).
5. Checked the error log /var/log/syslog/ and saw no errors regarding these cron tasks.
6. Tested with an output file: >> /home/root/Desktop/pi.log 2>&1. That didn’t provide me output.

**cronjob commands**

```
/2 * * * * Python /home/root/Desktop/pi.py
/2 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/root/Desktop/pi.py
/2 * * * * cd /home/root/Desktop/ Python pi.py
```

The Python script is a bit long. The main function is to retreive data from a usb device and store this in an sql database. See full code : https://github.com/gejanssen/slimmemeter-rpi/blob/master/p1db/p1uitlezerdb-ESMR50.py

Comment: Could it be that you are missing an asterisk `*` before forward slashes ?

Comment: If the raspi crond follows standards, it needs to be `*/2 * * * * command`in order to run every second minute. Also, **DO NOT chmod 777 a file owned and executed by root** that's a serious security risk

Comment: Unbelievable, that was the error. Thank you very much!